Separate build/release directory with conan and vscode
I would like to have build folder with subfolders for Debug and Release builds. So, I tried following to install dependencies:
conan install . --build=missing --profile=profiles/clang_debug.txt

Content of profiles/clang_debug.txt:
[buildenv]
CC=clang
CXX=clang++

[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Debug
compiler=clang
compiler.cppstd=17
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=17
os=Linux

This creates build/Debug/generators folder in which conan_toolchain.cmake resides alongside all other Conan generated stuff. Next I can do something like:
cd build/Debug
cmake ../../ -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=generators/conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
make

However, VSCode does not list any targets in project outline - like it has no knowledge about CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE. Is there a way I can create this project layout and share settings with other team members using json? I am not familiar with VSCode/Conan and I did not find anything so far. Following official guide for Conan looks bit incorrect since they are using --output-folder=build which creates additional build directory: build/build/Debug/generators. Conan version: 2.1.0, CMake version: 3.28.3, VSCode version: 1.87.2.

It depend what you have in your conanfile, either .txt or .py, it might have a layout() method or [layout]. The former in a conanfile.py is necessary for customization. There are other customization points as tools.cmake.cmake_layout:build_folder, tools.cmake.cmake_layout:build_folder_vars that can be used to control de output folders. In general it would be recommended to be able to use the default configuration without extra conf.

The https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues Github issues might be better for support and further discussion about the above.
